# I Want To Click Post Button On This WebPage

Tags: javascript, userscripts

I want to submit the form using javascript..
I have tried the codes below but they didn't work, the page just continue refreshing or did nothing.

```
    document.forms[0].submit(); 
    document.forms["create-discussion"].submit(); 
    document.getElementByID("submitButton").click();
    document.getElementByID("submitButton").submit();
```

Please here is the process to access to the webform
1st - www.yookos.com(login page) -- username(tolodo) password(loveworld)
2nd - https://www.yookos.com/discussion/create.jspa?containerID=5460&containerType=700

My Userscript Below fills in text but I still can't get it to submit

```
    // ==UserScript==
    // @name    discussioncrap code
    // @namespace   http://hayageek.com
    // @include http://www.yookos.*
    // @require http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js
    // @include https://www.yookos.com/discussion/create.jspa?containerID=5460&containerType=700
    // @version     1
    // ==/UserScript==

    var discussSubj = document.getElementById("subject");
    discussSubj.value = "okay";
    var discussBody = document.getElementById("wysiwygtext");
    discussBody.value = "Just Now";
    document.getElementByID("submitButton").click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Be careful about the fact that [javascript is case-sensitive](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_syntax.asp).

In the last line of your code, you use an undefined function: it should be document.getElementBy**Id**(), **not** document.getElementBy**ID**().